Looking for a recent Sci-Fi book where the people live in trees, their body chemistry has been altered to digest the "wrong-handed" local molecules
It's not the Alan Dean Foster book. I read it about two years ago. It's fairly recent, within the last 5 to 7 years. The main character gets exiled from his tree-town for spilling a pot of "magic" brew, and gets some on his leg, causing a partial reversal of his body chemistry.
Also his sister ends up being a conduit for uploaded/downloaded skills and personalities, initially a doctor but later on a systems engineer, etc.
Sound familiar to anyone?

This might be The Expert System's Brother by Adrian Tchaikovsky.  The story takes place on a world that was never supposed to have been colonized, and so the humans had to make some radical changes to their own physiologies to survive.
One major point of the story is the Tree of Life that supports their existence by constantly monitoring the colonists and tweaking their body chemistry as needed to keep them healthy.
The protagonist is a young man named Handry who has an accident that partially reverts his physiology to human normal.  His sister acts as a download point for personalities/memories of the original colony crew members.
